# Getting percentage of character variables and re-group small parts in R

Tags: r, character, grouping

I have been trying to write some small piece of code that can:

- Take a character variable ->
- Get percentages of all possible values taken by this variable ->
- Re-name the small percentages to "Other" instead of their original value.

I am working in `R`, just example:

```
#Toy data x:
x <-c("Other","Other","Other","","Office","Other","Other",
  "Other","Other","Sales","","Office","Other",
  "Mgr","Other","Other","Mgr","","Other","Office",
  "Other","ProfExe","Mgr","Mgr","Other")

x_freq <- plyr::count(x)
names(x_freq) <- c("Modality","Count")
x_freq$Prob <- x_freq$Count/sum(x_freq$Count)
small <- x_freq$Modality[...]
```

The `...` is just saying, if probability does not reach a certain level, `small` will be taking the variable name and then rename it to "Other". But my code does not look very neat and clean, I wonder if there are other simpler way to code it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just writing a function

```
small_to_other <- function(x, min.fraction=.05) {
    counts <- table(x)/length(x)
    x[x %in% names(counts)[counts<min.fraction]] <- "Other"
    x
}
```

Here I set the default to 5% so any category with less than 5% get gets to other. You can call it

```
small_to_other(x)
# changes "ProfExe" to Other
```

If you wanted to get rid of those with less than 15%, you can do

```
small_to_other(x, .15)
# change "ProfExe", "Office" and "" to "Other"
```

Comment: Thank you!! Much simpler and more elegant than my code!